# Is a URI containing a comma valid in a HTTP Link header?

Tags: java, http, rfc5988

Is the following HTTP Link header, containing a comma, valid?

```
Link: <http://www.example.com/foo,bar.html>; rel="canonical"
```

[RFC5988](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5988#section-5.3) says:

> Note that extension relation types are REQUIRED to be absolute URIs in
> Link headers, and MUST be quoted if they contain a semicolon (";") or
> comma (",") (as these characters are used as delimiters in the header
> itself).

This doesn't cover the #link-value however. That must be a URI-Reference as per RFC [3987](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3987#section-3.1) which seems to allow this. The link header itself can also have multiple values, from [RFC5988](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5988#section-5.3) section 5.5:

```
Link: </TheBook/chapter2>;
      rel="previous"; title*=UTF-8'de'letztes%20Kapitel,
      </TheBook/chapter4>;
      rel="next"; title*=UTF-8'de'n%c3%a4chstes%20Kapitel
```

I'm parsing this link header in Java using [BasicHeaderValueParser](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/message/BasicHeaderValueParser.html) from Apache HttpCore 4.4.9 using the following code:

```
final String linkHeader = "<http://www.example.com/foo,bar.html>; rel=\"canonical\"";
final HeaderElement[] parsedHeaders = BasicHeaderValueParser.parseElements(linkHeader, null);
        
for (HeaderElement headerElement : parsedHeaders)
{
    System.out.println(headerElement);
}
```

which tokenises on the comma and prints the following:

```
<http://www.example.com/foo
bar.html>; rel=canonical
```

Is this valid behaviour?

Comment: BWTW, RFC 5988 has been obsoleted by RFC 8288.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comma is of course valid.

What you're missing is that the BasicHeaderValueParser is *not* generic. It only supports certain HTTP header fields, and "Link" isn't one of them (see syntax description in https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/message/HeaderValueParser.html.

Answer (score 1):

[RFC 3986, section 3.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.3) clearly mentions, that a URI may contain sub-delimiters, which are defined in [section 2.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.2) and may contain a comma `,`.

RFC 5988 clearly states that the *relation types* must be quoted if they contain a comma and not the URI.

I think there is very little room for interpretation and it's IMHO an incomplete implementation on the HttpCore side.

The [BasicHeaderValueParser](https://github.com/Jean-Emile/org.apache.httpclient/tree/master/src/main/java/org/apache/http/message) uses the ',' as element delimiter, neglecting the fact that this character is a valid character for the header fields - which is probably ok for most cases, although not 100% compliant.

You may however provide your own custom parser as second argument (instead of `null`)